# At the time of login of a user, want to check the current time and compare it with previous login times in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, authentication

At the time of login of a user I want to check the current time and compare it with previous login time in JSP(JAVA). I stored the time at every login in database. Now I wanted to do that just compare the login time with average of previous login time and return true if the time is around similar with the user's usual login time. Otherwise return false. Can anyone suggest me a good function to do that. My code is as below,

```
public boolean login_checking(String username) {
    public boolean login = false;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select (case when ((timediff(time(now()),time(accesstime)))<'02:00:00') then 1 else 0 end)from tbl_login_history where uid = ?");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.first()) {
         //   login = rs.getInt(1) < 0;
         //   System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not exist");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return login;
}
```

Comment: Is your code working now?

Comment: The sql query is not correct. it doesn't give the correct answer. I just put those query to better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the code. I just change the query abow as follows,

```
SELECT (select count(*) from tbl_login_history where hour(accesstime) between 4 and 12 AND uid=?),(select count(*) from tbl_login_history where hour(accesstime) between 13 and 19 AND uid=?),(select count(*) from tbl_login_history where hour(accesstime) between 19 and 1 AND uid=?);
```

In this query I divided time into 3 different zones and checks the count of login in each zone. If more accurate time needed, the time can divided into more zones. For my system 3 is enough. Then I check from which zone the user has more login. If the user currently login in the usual time zone it return true. otherwise false.
Thanks for everyone who try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Have a column named usualtime or something,When the user login,

> 1.get usualtime from db.
>   2.If it is empty, insert into db.
>   3.If not empty get the current time and check if usualtime is near to it.
>   4.If near, usualtime = (usualtime+currenttime)/2, update new usualtime in db and return true
>   5.If not near don't update db and return false.

Comment: Well I got the idea. But the problem is I can't check the 3rd point you mention. Anyway thanks. :)

Comment: if the usualtime is not empty. i.e., if the user has logged in previously, you have to check if the current time is near to that time.. it does the same thing as                                  when ((timediff(time(now()),time(accesstime)))<'02:00:00'

Comment: Thanks @sonic for helping me. I make a little change in code. Its working perfectly.